# defaultCalendarForNewEvents failed

Tags: ios, calendar

When I try to call [newEventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents], it returns an error message says:

```
[707:907] defaultCalendarForNewEvents failed: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
[707:907] Error!Failed to save appointment. Description:Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x1fc679f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
```

The app runs for a long time. The problem came to me first time. The phone runs IOS6 Beta4. model is iphone 4.
Is there anyone knows when the defaultCalendarForNewEvents method will get failed? I can not get any useful information from googling.

Comment: I get this error AFTER I have successfully been granted authorization with `[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^{ run my code that test this }`

Answer (score 55):

On iOS6, Apple introduced a new privacy control that allows the user to control the accessibility of contacts and calenders for each app. So, on the code side, you need to add some way to request the permission. In iOS5 or before, we can always call

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    // iOS 6 and later
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            // code here for when the user allows your app to access the calendar
            [self performCalendarActivity:eventStore];
        } else {
            // code here for when the user does NOT allow your app to access the calendar
        }
    }];
} else {
    // code here for iOS < 6.0
    [self performCalendarActivity:eventStore];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Ios app wont be able to get any data from the Calendar on the iOS6 system if you don’t call the **– requestAccessToEntityType:completion:**  function to prompt a dialog to ask your users to grant access to your app to access the Calendar/Reminder . Code will look like:

```
//CalendarEventHandler.h  
@interface CalendarEventHandler : NSObject
{
EKEventStore *eventStore;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) EKEventStore *eventStore;


//CalendarEventHandler.m 
self.eventStore =[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if([self checkIsDeviceVersionHigherThanRequiredVersion:@"6.0"]) {
        [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

            if (granted){
                //---- codes here when user allow your app to access theirs' calendar.

            }else
            {
                //----- codes here when user NOT allow your app to access the calendar.  
            }  
        }];

    }else {
                //---- codes here for IOS < 6.0.

    }
```

//   Below is a block for checking is current ios version higher than required version.

```
 - (BOOL)checkIsDeviceVersionHigherThanRequiredVersion:(NSString *)requiredVersion
 {
  NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

   if ([currSysVer compare:requiredVersion options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
   {
       return YES;
   }

       return NO;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

`iOS6+` requires users authentication to save event to his device calendar.
Here is a code snippt:

```
    // save to iphone calendar
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        // iOS 6 and later
        // This line asks user's permission to access his calendar
        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
        {
            if (granted) // user user is ok with it
            {
                EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
                event.title  = aTitle;
                event.allDay = YES;

                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[UIApplicationSingleton sharedManager] aDateFormatter];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aaa"];
                event.startDate = event.endDate = //put here if start and end dates are same

                [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                NSError *err;

                [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

                if(err)
                    NSLog(@"unable to save event to the calendar!: Error= %@", err);

            }
            else // if he does not allow 
            {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:alertTitle delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"plzAlowCalendar", nil)  otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                return;
            }
        }];
    }

    // iOS < 6
    else
    {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title  = aTitle;
        event.allDay = YES;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[UIApplicationSingleton sharedManager] aDateFormatter];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aaa"];
        event.startDate = event.endDate = //put here if start and end dates are same

        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err;

        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

        if(err)
            NSLog(@"unable to save event to the calendar!: Error= %@", err);

    }
```

And check my [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237014/failing-to-save-ekreminder-in-ios-6/16213772#16213772) if you are facing trouble in setting alarm to the application.

Comment: I think the UIAlertView in the completion block will not work cause of calling UIKit from an other thread...

Comment: Submitted revision to correct issue pointed out by @tapmonkey.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.
I accidentally turn off the app access to calendar in Setting->Privacy on IOS6

Comment: I have the same problem. But my app does not ask for permission to access calendar. Why is that?

Comment: @BorutTomazin once you have given/denied permissions it will not disturb the user again bothering for permissions.

Comment: @Hercules add this option as solution. so you should accept it as answer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but finally find what was the reason.

My case was to add my Reminder and Calendar events, but I was using one `EKEventStore`. In the end I seperate them and problem dissapeared:

```
private static let calendarEventStore = EKEventStore()
private static let remindersEventStore = EKEventStore()
```

So now I'm using `calendarEventStore` for all things related to calendar event and `remindersEventStore` for reminder one.

——

In my opinion it was related to the fact that I requested `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` and `defaultCalendarForNewReminders()` in one `EKEventStore` entity.

Also this one from `EKEventStore` docs:

> Events, Reminders, and Calendar objects retrieved from an event store
>   cannot be used with any other event store

Answer (score 1):

### Swift form

*(based on @yunas answer)*

```
_estore = EKEventStore()
_estore.reset()

_estore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        println("allowed")
        /* ... */
    } else {
        println("not allowed")
    }           
}
```

It will open "Access" pop-up

Answer (score 0):

Go to Simulator/Device settings/Privacy/Calendars/YourApp Tap ON to allow calendar access.
And retry your code.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin users:

```
EKEventStore eventStore = new EKEventStore();
eventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Event, (bool granted, NSError e) =>
{
    if (granted)
    {
       //Your code here when user gief permissions
    }
});
```