# adding data to calendar not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, calendar

I am trying to add meeting details in calendar with below code. However it is not working. I always get error code (Else part is executing).

```
EKEventStore *eventSotre = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventSotre];

event.title= @"Event Title";

NSDate *duedate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.startDate = duedate;
// also tried with below
// event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:200 sinceDate:duedate];
event.endDate= [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:duedate];

NSArray *arrAlarm = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:duedate]];
event.alarms= arrAlarm;

[event setCalendar:[eventSotre defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
BOOL isSuceess=[eventSotre saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

if(isSuceess){
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[err description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];
}
[eventSotre release];
```

Any idea why I am facing this? I also have `#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>` in my code and I have added framework for the same too.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I think ur device version is IOS 6 right?

Comment: @Ganapathy : Yep, I found the solution too...

Comment: ya. me too tried.  ok..

Comment: @Ganapathy : Do you know how to set Alert time as 5 mins before?

Comment: Means u need to set alarm in ur calendar before 5 mins of end time right?

Comment: I got solution for that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link solved my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451544/1066828

The problem was I have iOS 6.