# Swift: Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. even answered 'Allow'

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent

I have following example where I get:

```
Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
```

This is a place:

```
  _estore = EKEventStore()
  _estore.reset()

_estore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: {(granted:Bool!, error:NSError!) in

   if  granted == true {

      println("#########   allowed calendar accounts   #########")

      var calendars = self._estore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) // <-- Exception
   }

})//block
```

I get proper popup `Allow/No` - I click on Allow and with debug I enter under `granted`

But get Exception.

from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454324/defaultcalendarfornewevents-failed) answer by `@yunas` I tried to wrap my code with:

```
if _estore.respondsToSelector(Selector("completion:")){ /* ... */ }
```

But in this case I never enter to that `if`

Whats is wrong with code?

Please help,

Answer (score 0):

```
_estore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: {(granted:Bool!, error:NSError!) in

   if  granted == true {
    let calendars : [EKCalendar] = _estore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) as [EKCalendar]
   }
```

Try this.

Comment: @snaggs : Has this solution helped you or ?