# Can we create our own default calendar programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ekcalendar

I am facing an issue while creating a calendar, i've signed out from iCloud to remove all other merged calendars. Now, there is only Gmail and yahoo calendars left and gmail is my default calendar. I want to create my own calendar and mark it as default but couldn't.

I used this `eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source` to assign source to my newly created calendar and got some error like this

> "This source doesn't allow to edit content etc."

Although this code returns true `print(eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.allowsContentModifications)`

Is there a way of creating your own, because we can see other apps i.e Google, Yahoo etc have created their own. Here's the code for creating new calendar

```
let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
 newCalendar.title = "Test Calendar"

    do {
         newCalendar.source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source
        try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
    } catch {
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Calendar could not save", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
              let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
              alert.addAction(OKAction)

              self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [defaultCalendarForNewEvents failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454324/defaultcalendarfornewevents-failed)